# 'require' and 'process' is not defined in ESlint. problem with node?

Tags: node.js, eslint

I had an error in my pipeline in `GitLab`. I changed the settings in `.eslint.json` using information from StackOverflow. But I still have problem.

My `.eslint.json` looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "semi": ["warn", "never"],
    "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
    "no-console": ["off"]
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 9
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "amd": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "$": true,
    "require": true
    "process": true
  },
  "root": true
}
```

In `env` I added `"adm": true` and in `globals` I added `"process": true` and `"require": true`.

The errors are:

**error  'require' is not defined  no-undef**

**error  'process' is not defined  no-undef**

The file where is the errors are looks like this:

```js
const qs = require("querystring");

const coEndpoint =
    process.env.NODE_ENV == "production"
```

So where is the problem? Is this a problem with env node? How can I fixed this?

Comment: add `"require": true` to the globals

Comment: Yes, but I also add `process:true` in globals, and still I have an errors.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, but still have a problem :/ What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `.eslint.json` to `.eslintrc.json` or make sure that `eslintConfig` is specified in your package.json

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Also make sure that `eslint` is started in the directory where your .eslintrc.json is and is not started with `--no-eslintrc` option.

Answer (score 197):

To specify environments in a configuration file, use the env key and specify which environments you want to enable by setting each to true. For example, the following enables the browser, es6 and Node.js environments:

In your `.eslintrc.js` file ;

```
...
env: {
   browser: true,
   node: true,    <<<<--- Add this
   es6: true
 },
...
```

Comment: during setup it ask me if eslint should be used for browser or node. I picked node.  But as you pointed out, it appears we also have to fill this section in as well. I would of never caught that.  Many thanks!

Comment: This answer worked for me. Instead of being called '.eslintrc.js' it was called '.eslintrc'.

Comment: adding ```node:true``` fixed my eslint error in my Webpack config file. Thank you!

Comment: `node:true` also helped me to resolve my eslint error. Tx!

Answer (score 0):

in your globals there is no comma (,) between your require and process. So add a comma there like this:

```json
"globals": {
  "$": true,
  "require": true,
  "process": true
},
```